# The proof of Neumann's theorem on the commuting probability of finite groups using Schur's theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0848) by Sean Eberhard that includes a proof of the following theorem:

THEOREM 2.4 (Neumann's theorem). Let $\epsilon>0$, and let $G$ be a finite group such that $\Pr(G)\geq\epsilon$. Then $G$ has a normal $2$-step nilpotent subgroup $H$ of $\epsilon$-bounded index such that $|[H,H]|$ is $\epsilon$-bounded.

Here, $\Pr(G)$ stands for the [commuting probability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_probability) of $G$, and $[H,H]$ is the commutator subgroup of $H$. The proof proceeds by first constructing a subgroup $K$ generated by the elements of $G$ that commute with a large enough number of elements, and showing that there are at most $\frac{\epsilon}{2}^\frac{12}{\epsilon}$ distinct commutators $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ with $x,y\in K$.

My issue is that the proof then states that "a classical theorem of Schur implies that $|[K,K]|$ is $\epsilon$-bounded." The theorem cited is from Robinson's *A course in the theory of groups*, 2nd edition:

**10.1.4** (Schur). If $G$ is a group whose center has a finite index $n$, then $|[G,G]|$ is finite and $([G,G])^n=1$.

But I fail to see how this theorem shows $|[K,K]|$ is $\epsilon$-bounded! My best guess is that $([K,K])^n=1$ places an upper bound on $|[K,K]|$. But wouldn't that bound be a function of $n=[K:Z(K)]$? So we would first have to show that $n$ itself is $\epsilon$-bounded, which I have not managed to do.

What exactly are the missing details of how Schur's theorem implies an $\epsilon$-bound on $|[K,K]|$? Thank you!

Comment: By the way, in case you're not aware of it, also check out this paper of Thomas Browning: https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.09402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Here are some more details.

*Claim 1:* Let $G$ be a group in which $|G:Z(G)| = n$. Then $|G'| \le n^{n^3}$.

*Proof:* The proof of [Robinson, 10.1.4] shows that $G'$ is generated by $\binom{n}{2}$ elements and $(G')^n = 1$. Let $N = G' \cap Z(G)$ and note $|G':N| \le |G:Z(G)| = n$. By using Schreier generators ([Robinson, 1.6.11]) it follows that $N$ is generated by $\binom{n}{2}n$ elements. Since $N$ is abelian it follows that $|N| \le n^{\binom{n}{2}n}$ and hence $|G'| \le n^{\binom{n}{2}n + 1} \le n^{n^3}$. $\square$

*Claim 2:* Let $G$ be a group in which there are only $n$ distinct commutators $[x,y]$. Then $|G'|$ is $n$-bounded.

*Proof:* Let the distinct commutators be $[x_1, y_1], \dots, [x_n, y_n]$. Then the subgroup $H = \langle x_1, \dots, x_n, y_1, \dots, y_n\rangle$ satisfies $H' = G'$. Therefore we may assume $G = H$. Since there are only $n$ distinct commutators we also have $|x^G| \le n$ for all $x \in G$. Therefore $|G:C_G(g)| \le n$ for all $g \in G$. Since $G$ is generated by $2n$ elements it follows that $|G:Z(G)| \le n^{2n}$. Now apply the previous claim. $\square$

Instead of referencing Schur's theorem [Robinson, 10.1.4] it might have been clearer to reference B. H. Neumann's "BFC theorem" [Robinson, 14.5.11]. (This is *not* the same as the Neumann in the question, but rather his father.) The BFC theorem states that if $|x^G| \le n$ for all $x$ then $G'$ is finite (and $n$-bounded). But I think the arguments above are marginally simpler than the proof of the BFC theorem.